# How to add "Class Prefix" field while creating xcode project template

Tags: ios, xcode, project-template, xcode-template

I am using a custom template that was defined already by some one. When I use that template, Xcode is not asking for `"Class Prefix"`. Because of this, what ever the classes that are created using this template are having a class name as project name followed by the class name we are giving like `"SampleProjectViewController.h"` or `"SampleProjectViewController.m"`.

Is there a way to add `"Class Prefix"` field and use this class prefix, while creating new classes, so that when I create a new class, expected class name would be `SPViewController.h` or `SPViewController.m` ?

Answer (score 2):

Add `com.apple.dt.unit.prefixable` to the Ancestors, it will automatically add the dialog. Then, use `___VARIABLE_classPrefix:identifier___` as a replacement string. Eg. let's say you have a class called Foo:

```
@interface ___VARIABLE_classPrefix:identifier___Foo : NSObject
@end

@implementation ___VARIABLE_classPrefix:identifier___Foo
@end
```

Files don't need to have that long prefix, you can simply do that in your Definitions by using something like `___VARIABLE_classPrefix:identifier___Foo.m` as the key and `Foo.m` as the `Path` (or however your naming works).