# Is there a way to get the class prefix (at runtime) of a given project?

Tags: objective-c, reflection, naming-conventions, objective-c-runtime

I want to construct a method which returns as a string the class prefix of the module it is operating in.

For example, if I have project with classes named `XYZMessage`, `XYZBusiness`, `XYZTransaction`... I want a function to return the string `XYZ`.

I have an implementation which uses the name of the appDelegate (The first capital letters except the last) to do this, but I would like a better way.  I would hope that Xcode defines a macro with this value or there's a key in the plist or something more concrete.  I don't want to `#define CLASS_PREFIX @"XYZ"` or anything hard-coded.

EDIT: *The Why*
The situation is I have a server who provides me the type (i.e. which class to construct) along with the information.

```
{
"type" : "merchant",
"data" : {
    "name" : "Super cool pizza",
    "location" : {
        "lat" : "123.000",
        "lon" : "23.0000"
    }
}
```

I have a class `AXQMerchant` which will take this (data) payload as it's initializer (unpack the keys/values, match the types to its properties, build sub-objects, etc.)

What I'm trying to avoid is this structure in my API handler:

```
NSString* objectType = ...; //server provided
NSString* classToConstruct; //our local type
if ([objectType isEqualToString:@"transaction"]) {
    classToConstruct = @"AXQTransaction";
} else if ([objectType isEqualToString:@"store"]) {
    classToConstruct = @"AXQStore";
    ... //a series of else-if blocks
} else if ([objectType isEqualToString:@"merchant"]) {
    classToConstruct = @"AXQMerchant";
}
id object = [[NSClassFromString(classToConstruct) alloc] initWithPayload:...];
//now do something with object
```

This section will easily grow unwieldy when my type list is >20 types.  What I want to write is:

```
classToConstruct = [classPrefix() stringByAppendingString:[objectType capitalizedString]];
id object = [[NSClassFromString(classToConstruct) alloc] initWithPayload:...];
```

---

For those who are curious; my current implementation is...

```
str = NSStringFromClass([[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate class]); //could be [self class], instead...
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    unichar c = [str characterAtIndex:i];
    if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') { //if c is not a capital we're at prefix end (+1 extra)
        return [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, i - 1)];
    }
}
return nil;
```

This is `dispatch_once()`'d so I only calculate it when the app is opened the first time.

Comment: What kind of behavior are you looking for if you have multiple classes in the project that have a different prefix? (Like, XYZMessage, XYZBusiness, XYZTransaction, AAAPerson, AAAClass, AAAContact.) I don't think "class prefix" is a well enough defined concept. Class prefixes are totally arbitrary. What are you interested in using this information for?

Comment: `isKindOfClass:` is _usually_ sufficient. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @CrimsonChris see the Edit section.  Basically I want to remove the checks altogether (these types share a common protocol for building them)

Comment: Interesting puzzle, but I vote for the preprocessor definition. Put it in the project settings.

Comment: @ItaiFerber when you create a new project in Xcode there's an option to put in a generic class prefix; _that's_ the value I'd like to get (other prefixes aren't important).

Comment: I agree with Josh. I'm interested in what this is applicable _for_, though. To what end is this useful? I ask because I'm curious. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project's class prefix [seems to be available to an Xcode template file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17831041/603977) via the replacement string `___VARIABLE_classPrefix:identifier___`, so one possibilty would be to create either a custom .pch or header file template. The header can then expose the prefix as either a macro or an `NSString`.

Comment: +1. This is exactly what Ryan is looking for (according to his comments).

Answer (score 0):

Use NSStringFromClass to get the class name and then return the first three characters of the string.

```
NSString *mystr = NSStringFromClass([instance class]);
return [mystr substringToIndex:3];
```

Comment: This requires you to know how long the prefix is. It may not always be 3 characters long.